# Icons in navbar dont stay inline

Tags: html, css, sass

So, I dont know what happened but suddenly my icons changed to be in vertical one on another. Here is the code:
Css:

```
    .float-right {
  float: right;
  height: inherit;
}

.icons-container {
  margin-right: 1vw;
  position: relative;
  width: 10vw;
}

.icons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  font-weight: 400;
  width: inherit;

  & a {
    color: $secondary-color;
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="float-right icons-container">
      <span class="icons">
        <a href="#"><i class="flaticon-twitter-logo-button"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="flaticon-github-logo"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="flaticon-instagram-logo"></i></a>
      </span>

    </div>
```

Here a screenshot:
[Icons one on top another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oigvN.png)
Screenshot of chrome dev tools:
[DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M3gq.png)

Comment: From the code you've posted the icons should not be on top of each other, so anything we could say would be pure conjecture. You need to recreate the problem with minimal code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: It's 2018 out there. Try to use **flex-box** which is a great tool and now supported by any modern browser and many obsolete ones.

Comment: I have to learn flex box, lel. @Sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to display horizontally

```
.icons a {
display: inline-block;
}
```